# Downloading blob (zip) from one endpoint and uploading to different endpoint

Tags: vue.js, axios, postman, blob, fetch-api

I'm trying to download a zip from one endpoint and upload to another from a FE VueJS app, but it ends up corrupted on upload.  I can do it with fileSaver but was hoping to skip the intermediate step of dropping it onto a HDD.  If I download and POST it with Postman it works fine, so I suspect there's an issue with the responseType or blob type etc, but there's a lot of combinations & permutations. cURL works fine as well, but obviously not applicable here.

This is the code so far, the fetch code/config is from Postman, but how the uploaded file is stored/represented in Postman is opaque. The zipEndpointUp is an endpoint that consumes the file but it returns 'invalid archive'.  localhost:8080 is proxied to the actual server to avoid CORs issues.

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/zipDirDown/download.zip, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: "Basic xxx",
                    mode: "no-cors",
                    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                }
            }).then(res => {
                const blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: "octet/stream"});

                let myHeaders = new Headers();
                myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic xxx");

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("file", blob, "newZipFile.zip");
                formData.append("name", "newZipFile Name");

                var requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    body: formData,
                    redirect: 'follow'
                };

                fetch("http://localhost:8080/zipEndpointUp", requestOptions)
                    .then(response =>
                        response.text())
                    .then(result =>
                        console.log(result))
                    .catch(error =>
                        console.log('error', error));
            })
```

[image: Blob in console:]

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I needed to await the res promise (and change the Blob type):

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/zipDirDown/download.zip, {
headers: {
    Authorization: "Basic xxx",
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    }
}).then(res => {
    const asyncBlob = await res.blob();
    const blob = new Blob([asyncBlob], {type: "application/zip"});
})
```